# Submitting HTML in Pardot form

Tags: pardot

We are starting to leverage the Pardot API by submitting our custom, in-house forms to a Pardot form handler.  From our form we want to send a small chunk of HTML in a hidden field and have it end up in a Pardot field - and have that HTML display rendered in the Pardot backend.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can post HTML content to a custom Pardot field. But this content will be displayed in Pardot without rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden Fields (on Pardot Forms, or via javascript on a Form Handler) can be pass information from the form front end to the Pardot database.  However,the Pardot backed does not support rich text / html as a data type.